# Clearing image and draw information on it

Tags: c#, drawing

Hi I want to draw some information on an image in c#. I wrote this code and it works:

```
Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(@"G:\Cert_template.png");
Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);
g.DrawString(cert_id, new Font("B  Zar", 3,System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Black, new Point(85, 95));
g.DrawString(date_cert, new Font("B  Zar", 3, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Black, new Point(85, 135));
g.DrawString(s1 + s3, new Font("B  Zar", 4, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Black, new Point(90, 290));
g.DrawString(s4, new Font("B  Zar", 3, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Black, new Point(480, 360));
g.DrawString(date_exam, new Font("B  Zar", 3, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Black, new Point(170, 515));
g.DrawString(Convert.ToString(mark), new Font("B  Zar", 3, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Black, new Point(520, 600));
g.DrawString(lvl, new Font("B  Zar", 3, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Black, new Point(150, 600));
g.DrawString(prvnc, new Font("B  Zar", 3, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Black, new Point(170, 780));
g.DrawString(center, new Font("B  Zar", 3, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Black, new Point(310, 870));
g.DrawString(inst, new Font("B  Zar", 3, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Black, new Point(150, 870));
CaptureScreen(g,imgCounter);
```

My image is the same for all information I write. I've put this code in a loop and it draws the image but for different information it overwrites previous image. I want to clear image and write on it again without overwriting.

EDIT

After that I send `g` to a function to show in a picture box:

```
 private void CaptureScreen(Graphics g,int imgCounter)
    {
        /*This method captures a snapshot of screen and 
         * adds it to the ImageFlowLayoutPanel
         */


        bmp.Save("snap" + imgCounter.ToString() + ".png", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);

        //creating a picturebox control and add it to the flowlayoutpanel
        PictureBox tempPictureBox = new PictureBox();

        //generates a thumbnail image of specified size
        tempPictureBox.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
        tempPictureBox.Image = bmp.GetThumbnailImage(600, 700,
                               new Image.GetThumbnailImageAbort(ThumbnailCallback),
                               IntPtr.Zero);
        tempPictureBox.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(50,50);

        tempPictureBox.Click += new EventHandler(this.tempPictureBox_Click);
        ImageFlowLayoutPanel.Controls.Add(tempPictureBox);

    }

    //This click event will be used to display the enlarged images
    private void tempPictureBox_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        PreviewPictureBox.Image = ((PictureBox)sender).Image;
    }
    public bool ThumbnailCallback()
    {
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: Just draw some rectangle as background first... Or there some other problem (it is sort of unclear what you try to overwrite and what you are trying to keep).

Comment: All the information that I'm drawing such as cert_id,date_cert ,... will change and at the end I must have up to 20 image with different information.The problem is when it's overwrites the text is messed up.

Comment: Is your question than "how to create 20 images in a loop"? You are missing that portion of the code (and can safely replace all `DrawString` code in sample with single `g.DrawString(index.ToString()...)`; call to make sample smaller.

Comment: what does `g.DrawString(index.ToString()...)` do? What should I put instead of `...`?

Comment: I just wanted to show that you just need **one** call to `DrawString` to demonstrate what you are trying to do. There is absolutely no reason to have 10+ almost identical lines in sample posted to SO - instead would be much more appreciated to have clear sample of code you have problem with rather than random pieces of some program.

Comment: It's not random. I use the EDIT part to show thumbnails of drawn image in a flow layout panel and enlarge the pictures in apicture box by click on thumbnail.But cause I have several information and for all of them the background image is the same when I preview the images the information for different images are overwritten on each other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possibility is to create a temporary bitmap, based on the original one,
for each cycle.

Please not that I made your Graphics instance be disposed immediately 
when no longer needed (by means of the using clause) and note that the Graphics instance
is build on top of the `newBitmap` not of the original one.

Also make sure that you consume the `newBitmap` reference, at the end of the cycle
instead of the `bmp` reference which simply holds the original background.

```
Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(@"G:\Cert_template.png");


for ( ... ) {

  Bitmap newBitmap = new Bitmap(bmp);
  using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(newBitmap)) {

    // somehow alter cert_id, date_cert, etc...

    g.DrawString(cert_id, new Font("B  Zar", 3,System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Black, new Point(85, 95));
    g.DrawString(date_cert, new Font("B  Zar", 3, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Black, new Point(85, 135));
    g.DrawString(s1 + s3, new Font("B  Zar", 4, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Black, new Point(90, 290));
    g.DrawString(s4, new Font("B  Zar", 3, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Black, new Point(480, 360));
    g.DrawString(date_exam, new Font("B  Zar", 3, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Black, new Point(170, 515));
    g.DrawString(Convert.ToString(mark), new Font("B  Zar", 3, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Black, new Point(520, 600));
    g.DrawString(lvl, new Font("B  Zar", 3, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Black, new Point(150, 600));
    g.DrawString(prvnc, new Font("B  Zar", 3, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Black, new Point(170, 780));
    g.DrawString(center, new Font("B  Zar", 3, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Black, new Point(310, 870));
    g.DrawString(inst, new Font("B  Zar", 3, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Black, new Point(150, 870));

    // and here you do something with your newBitmap instance
    // (for example: you save it to another filename)

  }

}
```

Comment: I've tried it and it's clear everything. I just want to clear what I've drawn and redraw new information

Comment: Can you just say `g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp)` again? Or do you not want to permanently clear your changes?

Comment: You didn't say that there initially existed a background, for that particular image. Is that what you're saying ? You didn't mention that.

Comment: Check out the latest EDIT. Now it should preserve the background